# Paypal Transactions not showing up in Sandbox, but appearing in notifications

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the PHP-SDK to send REST requests to Paypal.

My transactions seem to succeed, both accounts get notifications, the seller getting "Notification of payment received" and the buyer "Receipt for Your Payment to xxxxx's Test Store" respectively. Both accounts' balances change according to the transaction. Yet there are no transactions shown in the transactions tab.

What's going on?

Comment: You aren't seeing the transaction in either sandbox account?  Are you sure you're checking the same account that is being used in the API transaction?

Answer (score 20):

That's because they don't show up there (a recent change), only failed transactions show up there for debugging purposes.

You want to log into sandbox.paypal.com with your dummy buyer account to see your list sandbox transactions, it's that simple.

Comment: Wow! I don't see THAT anywhere in the docs.  A great place for it would be, say, on the actual Sandbox Transactions page, where one would think they'd appear!! SMH.

Comment: They do this just to make developers waste time trying to figure out what went wrong. Ugh!